# How to show all possible numbers in array form from a number

Tags: php, numbers, integer

I'm new to php programming, I'm sure this it not that difficult. I have a number(example:7526) and need it to show all possible numbers it can achieve like:

7526
5276
2675
2676
5267
etc......

I need all numbers to show.....thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Try searching for "permutation"

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: thanks, I got it to work permutation was exactly what I was looking for.